# An example that saddle point exists but max-min condition fails

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-analysis

Let us first recall a classical theorem for saddle points.

> Suppose that $X,Y$ are two reflexive Banach spaces, 
>   $E\subset X$ and $F\subset Y$ are two non-empty closed convex sets. Assume that
>
> (1) For any $y\in F$, the mapping $x\to f(x,y)$ is l.s.c. and quasi-convex
>
> (2) For any $x\in E$, the mapping $y\to -f(x,y)$ is l.s.c. and quasi-convex.
>
> (3) There exits some $(x_0,y_0)\in E\times F$ such that $f(x_0,y)\to -\infty$ as $\|y\|\to +\infty$ and $f(x,y_0)\to\infty$ as $\|x\|\to+\infty$.
>
> Then  there exits a saddle point $(x^*,y^*)\in E\times F$ such that 
>   $$
> \max_{y\in F}f(x^*,y)=f(x^*,y^*)= \min_{x\in E} f(x,y^*) \quad (A)
> $$

I know that if $E$ and $F$ are weakly compact, then the condition about can be written as 
$$
\min_{x\in E}\max_{y\in F}f(x,y)=\max_{y\in F}\min_{x\in E}f(x,y).   \quad (B)
$$
I'm interesting in find an counter-example that the functional  satisfies (1)-(3) and hence $(A)$ but not $(B)$. The key part seem to allow $E$ and $F$ to be unbounded.

Comment: where can I see a proof for this result?

Comment: @Redshoes You can see this from E. Zeidler's "Nonlinear functional analyis with applications".

Comment: @Redshoes Or, you can find the results from "Methods in Nonlinear Analysis"

Comment: @Icesea are you still interested? I think (A) implies (B) without further assumptions. The quantity in (A) is geq minMax and leq Maxmin. The reverse inequality is min-max inequality.